# t-test without raw data

Tags: r, statistics

I seem to be bogged down in computing an interval in a question.

I can do it manually but seem unable to find the correct R t.test syntax to do the question (all the googling point me to raw data) when I have summaries.

My scenario is one in which I have two groups having a constant variance.

The mean of the new group is 3 and sd of 0.6 while that of the old group is 5 with an sd of 0.68.
I want to computer the 95% confidence for the differences in mean between the new and old systems.

```
n <- 10
nM <- 3
nS <- 0.6
oM <- 5
oS <- 0.68
```

Comment: It appears to be a Stat 101 homework problem. Such problems are usually not welcome here.

Comment: A search for "pooled t-test" might help you.

Comment: @andrey-shabalin: I assure you that it is not my intent to get someone to do my homework. I **can** work the correct answer by following the instructions at http://onlinestatbook.com/2/estimation/difference_means.html. My problem is that I am unable to get an R function to do the work. I was expecting an R function to handle this automatically. I hope this clarifies my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = sample(1:10,100, replace=TRUE)
y = sample(1:10,100, replace=TRUE)

s.x= sd(x)
s.y= sd(y)

mu.x = mean(x)
mu.y = mean(y)

se = sqrt(s.x^2/length(x) + (s.y^2/length(y)))

t = (mu.x-mu.y)/se
```

For confidence interval try your research on internet.

Comment: How does this answer OP's question? You seem to stop at exactly the point the question starts.

Comment: Here is the remainder: CI_0.95 = (mu.x-mu.y) -+ 2.04*se

Comment: By the way this question has not much to do with R. The R syntax is very basic. The post should be migrated

Comment: @yujia-hu: Thank you. I was expecting a R function to do the work. From reading the comments posted here, it seems that such a function was in my imagination :-).